# create anonymous token API GITHUB

Tags: github-api

I search how I can have a anonymous token for github API. I have found the personnel API, and my script work, but my script is in Javascript for a website ( so very unsecure for my account ).
Do you Know, how I can have an anonymous token, or if I need create a new account on github just for this ?
( i have a student account on github, and I can access to the developer program )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with a human github API, and I understand how it's work .

For make an anonymous token, you need just a token scopelless, in the scope list of this token, don't select any scope.

For test go https://api.github.com/user/keys?access_token=
without scope "read:public_key", you see an error, with scope, you see all your public key, with details

**Edit ( thx jasonrudolph )** : it's not really an anonymous token, if we check : https://api.github.com/user/?access_token= , you can see master account information for this token

Comment: It's true that a scopeless token doesn't provide *privileged* access to your account (e.g., no access to private repositories, no ability to delete SSH keys, etc.), but it's not "anonymous". The token is still associated with your account, and you can use the token to identify your GitHub username. If you use the token to access https://api.github.com/user, you'll see that identifies your account.